# Change image via shared preferance from one activity to another android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, sharedpreferences, android-imageview

I have implemented image chooser option from gallery in my app. After choosing the image from gallery ot taking picture from camera , I keep it in shared preferance so that user can see that image when they come back again to this activity. Now I want to use that image in another activity. But I do not know how can I pass that imagr from that frgament class to main activity.

Here is my code for image chooser and keep it in shared Preferance.

```
public class ViewProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


    private ImageView image;

    private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;

    String userChoosenTask;
    Bitmap bm;
    String currentPhotoPath;
    Uri uri;

    private String UPLOAD_URL = Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_profile, container, false);


        image=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        saveData();
        return rootView;
    }
    public void saveData(){
        .....
        if (results.size() > 0) {
            ......

            SharedPreferences preferences =
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            String mImageUri = preferences.getString("image", null);
            if (mImageUri != null) {
                image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mImageUri));
                System.out.println("imageuri"+Uri.parse(mImageUri));
            } else {
                Glide.with( this )
                        .load(Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL+mail)
                        .thumbnail(0.5f)
                        .override(200,200)
                        .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .into( image);

                System.out.println(Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL+mail);
            }

    }


    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(uri);
        this.getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

        SharedPreferences preferences =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(uri));
        editor.commit();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void onCaptureImageResult() {
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromPath(currentPhotoPath, 200, 200);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        compressBitMap(bitmap);
    }

    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
        uri = data.getData();
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            currentPhotoPath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(currentPhotoPath));
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            currentPhotoPath = uri.getPath();
        }

        SharedPreferences preferences =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(uri));
        editor.commit();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath);
        compressBitMap(bm);
    }
}
```

And this is Another activity where I want to see that image by using sharedprefenace

**Edited Code**

```
    public class MainOptionPage extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


    private ImageView imgProfile;
    RealmResults<MyColleagueModel> results;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ....
        // Navigation view header

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        navigationHeader= navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        ....
        imgProfile = navigationHeader.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        // load nav menu header data
        loadNavHeader();

        //setupDrawerContent(navigationView);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
     }

   private void loadNavHeader() {

        GlobalClass globalClass = new GlobalClass();
        String mEmail = globalClass.getEmail_info();

        Realm profileRealm;
        profileRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        results = profileRealm.where(MyColleagueModel.class).equalTo("mail", mEmail).findAll();

        //fetching the data
        results.load();

        // name, website
        String name=null;
        String profile_image;
        byte[] profile_byte = new byte[0];

       // if( globalClass.readDatafromStorage().contains("ACTIVATE")) {
            name = " ";
            if (results.size() > 0) {
                name = results.get(0).getName().toString();
            }
            profile_image = globalClass.getImage_urlpath();


            profile_image = globalClass.getImage_urlpath();
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String mImageUri = preferences.getString("image", null);
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            imgProfile.setImageURI( Uri.parse(mImageUri));

        System.out.println("imageuri"+Uri.parse(mImageUri));
        } else {
            Glide.with( this ).load( profile_image )
                    .thumbnail( 0.5f )
                    .override( 200, 200 )
                    .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
                    .into( imgProfile );
            Log.d( "--LoginPage_NAME--", name );
        }

        txtName.setText( name );
        txtWebsite.setText(mEmail);


        Glide.with(this).load(profile_image)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .override(200,200)
                .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgProfile);

        // TODO: 11/9/17 set bitmap in imageview by removing below comment

    }
```

Comment: Try the same which you have done in ViewProfileFragment  activity `SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); String mImageUri = preferences.getString("image", null);` @tamrezh21

Comment: you don't need to pass the image to another activity, just do the same thing you used for fetching image from SharedPreference.

Comment: @VikasTiwari I hae edited the code in main option, but still I did not get any picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're storing it in the preferences, you can access it via the prefs as mentioned in the comments above.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = preferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
String mImageUri = preferences.getString("image", null);

if (mImageUri!=null){
   // load image
}
```

Credits @vikas-tiwari

Comment: I have edited the code but I donot see updated image in MainOptionPage

Comment: Because you need a way to refresh the image. Make your `loadNavHeader()` method public, inside your fragment cast your getActivity () to the main activity something like this: 
`if (getActivity() instanceof MainAcitivty){ ((MainAcitivity)getActivity()).loadNavHeader()}` which will update the image in the activity when it is changed in the fragment. Don't forget to add it after the you save the uri of the new image in prefs

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it is workinng, I will update the question.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. @VikasTiwari you answered it originally, you do deserve the credit.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already suggested, you can use shared to access the image. 
The advice I give you is to create a single class where you create the sharedpreferences and retrieve the instance at any time. 
Example:

```
public class MySharedPreferences {

    private static MySharedPreferences mInstance;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySharedPreferences(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
    }

    public static synchronized MySharedPreferences getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySharedPreferences(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }


    public boolean saveData(String data1, String data2) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY1, data1);
        editor.putString(KEY2, data2);
        return editor.commit();
    }

 public String getData1() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY1, null);
    }
}
```